How can a signer's key be missing from an account?
From my understanding, each account needs to be signed in by its creator when its initialized. Then, can the signer key be ever missing? And is it a good practice to verify if an account is signed to validate it?
The question inspired by: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/memo/program/src/processor.rs#L18

Not always true. Usually you are signing because you are going to pay for the creation of the account (ie. payer = signer). If you are using anchor, using the Signer struct will do the validation for you.

Can the signer key ever be missing?
No, the signer key cannot be missing when an account is initialized. The creator of the account must sign the transaction to initialize it. This is necessary for the system to recognize the authority behind the account and ensure that only authorized users can modify it.
Is it a good practice to verify if an account is signed to validate it?
Yes, it is a good practice to verify if an account is signed. Checking for the signer ensures that the operations being performed on the account are authorized and helps prevent unauthorized access or modifications. This adds an extra layer of security to your program.
Generally i think this question is related to this : Anchor: does an account being initialized (not PDA) need to be a signer?
